# Bootstrap 4 modal slide in from right as side panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm upgrading from Bootstrap 3 to 4 and am having difficulty replicating a customization I made to Modals so that they would slide in from the right and have full height and attached to the right of the screen, like a side panel.

With Bootstrap 3 you could do:

```
.modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

However it looks like BS4 has changed the way it handles modals and I can't figure out how to replicate this functionality.

If it makes a difference, I'm using ember-bootstrap and SCSS.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Post the html too please